# How to create a template in SQL Server Management Studio for retrieving the data and segregate the data according to the requirement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

I need to build a template by using **SSMS** for extracting data from server and the same data should display according to the requirement.

For example I have data pertaining to 5 different Sizes. Each size have 4 variables which I need to extract from server. Once we get the data , that data should display according to the size.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Its Stored Procedure in SQL Server. You need to write required logic inside the procedure and execute it from an application.